# Access A Link Inside A NAV Element

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I'm trying to access an HTML element using Selenium (C#) but I'm currently having trouble. The element is located within a structure like this:

```
<nav>
   <ul class="menu"> id="menu">
      <li id="ignore"> </li>
      <li id="test_tab">
         <a href="/.../..." title="Update">Update</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to access and click "Update". What is the best method to access this link? I have tried .findElement(By.Id("test_tab")) and similar without success. Once it has been selected I then plan to call .click().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple!  First you need to determine what element is receiving the click.  in this case, the `<a>` will be.   Just use a simple css selector.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul#menu li#test_tab > a[title='Update']")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks sircapsalot. I don't know why I didn't try a css selector.

Comment: CSS much faster and simpler than xpath.  Plus it's very practical for other development. I'd invest your time with learning CSS selectors.  I'm open for consulting if you need it, too `:)` http://www.airpair.com/selenium/selenium-expert-daniel-davison

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select the li element and hence not possible to click the link. For selecting 'a' there could be multiple options.

1)

```
.findElement(By.LinkText("Update")).click()
```

2)

```
IWebElement update = driver.findElement(By.Id("test_tab"));
update = update.findElement(By.TagName("a"));
update.click();
```

3) You could use xpaths to directly select 'a'.